# Excel file as HTTP post method response

Tags: excel, http, post, get

In my application, I use GET method to get a Excel file back. The url actually contains the parameters that server needs to generate the Excel file. However, sometimes, the parameters may become so long (more then 2000 characters).

I am considering using POST method, but it does not seem that POST method can return a document. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nop, how you request, say `GET`, `PUT` and `POST`, doesn't necessarily affect the server you response.

How to make the response depends on the program on server. If you want to send a binary file after a POST request is totally cool.

Just take a look at sites like megaupload, rapidshare, etc. All of them will send you a file after you `POST` the recaptcha code.